# iPhoto files compressed in Time Capsule. Where is the original size?

Tags: photos.app, photos, time-capsule, compression

My 8 year old iMac died some days ago. Fortunately, I have everything backed up on my Time Capsule. I just tried to get my photos from iPhoto off it, but realized that all my shots have been compressed down to something between 30 to 80 kB instead of the couple of MBs they should be. Is there any way I can retrieve my photos at their full quality? All my SLR shots just look horrible now.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing the Thumbnails that iPhoto creates for display in the iPhoto Window rather than the original files. How are you restoring?

Answer (score 1):

Find your iPhoto Library, which should be in Pictures. It's a package. Control-click on it and select *Show Package Contents*. You will see a *Masters* folder. Make a copy of that folder and all its contents by dragging it to the Desktop or anywhere you like, holding down the Option key at the same time — the green plus icon appears. If it doesn't, you're not making a copy.